# Excel vba for determining a cell based on color and then coloring the next uncolored row directly above it

Tags: vba, excel, search

I have a sheet that is automatically formatted based when the button is clicked. My issue is trying to color a row based upon the current color of another row. Basically the sheet is something like this:

numerical part level (0-1-2- or 3) ----    serial number ------   part name ------  etcc..

numerical part level (0-1-2- or 3) ----    serial number ------   part name ------  etcc..

numerical part level (0-1-2- or 3) ----    serial number ------   part name ------  etcc..

i currently have the parts that are part of an assembly formatted green, this is based off of their numerical part level in column 1, for an assembly component all the part levels are 2 so this is easy. My problem comes in i want to format the row that is the title of the assembly components in blue, the title of the assembly components however has a part level of 1 just like every other part in the entire component so i cannot simply ask excel to color all level 1 with blue!

So i originally tried an offset command to find the row with green and select the row above it to highlight blue, this does not work as the number of level 2 components vary so the title component is not always the row directly above it. I have no other type of data to search upon to try to color the blue cell.

I am thinking of a code that searches through the lines until it finds a green line, then moves itself up from there until it finds the next uncolored line and colors it blue. Then moves on to the next row until it reaches the end of the range.

I have no idea how to approach something like this, anyone help?? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub colorCells()
    Dim x, i as Integer, color As Long
    Dim flg As Boolean

    'set the flag
    flg = True
    For Each x In Range("A:A")
        color = x.Interior.color
        If color = vbGreen Then
            If flg Then
                For i = x.Row To 1 Step -1
                x.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.color = vbBlue
                flg = False
            End If
        Else: flg = True
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

To get the color code do this:

```
Sub getColor()
    MsgBox ActiveCell.Interior.Color
End Sub
```

If you need to find the first uncolored row above any block of green rows, try this:

```
Sub colorCells()
    Dim x, color As Long, i As Integer
    Dim flg As Boolean

    'set the flag
    flg = True
    For Each x In Range("A:A")
        color = x.Interior.color
        If color = vbGreen Then
            If flg Then
                For i = 1 To x.Row
                    If x.Offset(-i, 0).Interior.color = 16777215 Then
                        x.Offset(-i, 0).Interior.color = vbBlue
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next i
                flg = False
            End If
        Else: flg = True
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks but this did not work, it actually didn't color anything at all, but if it had it appears its only an offset command to color the row directly above the green isn't it? That wont work as there are multiple green rows in a row and the blue one won't always be the row directly above. basically this was my color finding code with your addition:

Comment: 'Finds assy components and colors row green
            With .Cells(Lrow, "A")
               If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                    If .Value = "2" Then .EntireRow.Interior.color = vbGreen
               End If
            End With
Dim x, color as Long
Dim rng as Range
Rng=”A:A”
For Each x in rng

Comment: color = x.Interior.Color
    If color = vbGreen Then
        x.offset(-1,0).Interior.Color = vbBlue
    End If
Next 
        Next Lrow
    End With
    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With